Ionic/Angular upgrade to SDK 34. Error during build: Could not find com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1
My project was building fine until I changed android-targetSdkVersion to 34 from 33. I am getting below error during the build.
Advise.
WARNING:Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data form
ats.
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34
This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32
This warning can be suppressed by adding
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties
The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34

Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
The RenderScript APIs are deprecated. They will be removed in Android Gradle plugin 9
.0. See the following link for a guide to migrate from RenderScript: https://develope
r.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate


Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/voll
ey-1.1.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-
1.1.1.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/android/volley/volley/1.1.1/volley-1.1.1.pom
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/app/src/main/libs/volley-1.
1.1.jar
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/app/src/main/libs/volley.ja
r
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/app/libs/volley-1.1.1.jar
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/app/libs/volley.jar
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/libs/volley-1.1.1.jar
- file:/C:/My Projects/emarketmb/platforms/android/libs/volley.jar
Required by:
project :app > com.google.android.libraries.maps:maps:3.1.0-beta


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradl
e 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and dete
rmine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_l
ine_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 14s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\My Projects\emarketmb\platforms\android\gradlew c
dvBuildDebug -b C:\My Projects\emarketmb\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova.cmd build android --debug exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

